# What do you say when referring to labor for an adverb?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, analogy

Analogy:

> Education : academically :: Labor : ?

I'm trying to fit in something to go here:

> ... not only do I have to do well academically, but also _____ (in my labor)

Parentheses not included.

What can fit in that blank?

Comment: *in my work*, or *professionally*, or *practically* if you are contrasting academia and work in analogy to theory and practice.

Comment: As in manual labor.

Comment: Wow, my grammar is terrible, and I'm a native speaker! Edited.

Comment: Or you could just go with ***work-wise***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are speaking about manual labor, consider the adverb form of vocation, "vocationally".  In American English, 'vocational education' refers idiomatically to education in a skilled trade, such as plumbing, electrical work, or carpentry.

[Vocational](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocationally)

> of, relating to, or concerned with a vocation
>
> of, relating to, or undergoing training in a skill or trade to be pursued as a career

... where [vocation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vocation) means

> the work in which a person is employed

Answer (score 2):

The normal word here though you want is probably *professionally*.

> From the moment students enroll at *X* College they are empowered to succeed both academically and professionally.

(Quote anonymized to not advertise any particular school.)

Also, you may want to look at the grammar of your sentence again, because I do not think as it stands it is grammatical: "I have to good academically"?

Comment: Last paragraph, LOL! I will fix it now, how did that happen?